# What is the longest anime title?

Tags: anime-history

So I was browsing around, finding a new anime to watch. And came along, *Ore no Nounai Sentakushi ga, Gakuen Love Comedy wo Zenryoku de Jama Shiteiru OVA* and found it to be a very long name.

Is this the longest anime name or is there an anime with a longer name out there?

Comment: I assume you just mean in only romanized?

Comment: @アズーサ Yeah only romanized

Comment: Just on a pointer: There are some anime series that only have an english name such as DRAMAtical murder.

Comment: I don't think OVA should be included as part of the name as its not.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Okay, so I have been able to find a definitive answer!

> Naruto Narutimate Hero 3: Finally a Clash! Jonin VS Genin!! Indescriminate Grand Melee Tournament Meeting!!

is the longest titled anime with a large 107 characters or 87 characters without non-alphanumeric characters

Second Place goes to:

> Digimon Adventure 02: Zenpen Digimon Hurricane Jouriku!! - Kouhen Chouzetsu Shinka!! Ougon no Digimental

With 104 characters, 85 alphanumeric

And Third,

> Dragon Ball Z Special: Tatta Hitori no Saishuu Kessen - Freezer ni Idonda Z Senshi Son Gokuu no Chichi

102 characters, 82 without.

I discovered this by writing a small Python script to iterate through a dump of AniDB's database of anime titles and check each one, [which you can find on their site](http://wiki.anidb.net/w/API)

If anyone is interested, you can find the script here: https://gist.github.com/ianfhunter/43599d30384b9b7aa0c6 (but I only hacked it up in 5 minutes, so it's nothing special)

(The shortest is C)

Comment: plain awesome ;)

Comment: Just noticed u did the alpha count that nails it for composite names.

Comment: What is the *print "45539 == "* for?

Comment: oh, I was making sure it was reading all the lines of the database file :P it's completely irrelevant to the outcome and I have edited it out now

Comment: While these are certainly long, I don't think I see it as definitive. AniDB has their system of grouping and naming, but it's far from the only possible system. If they had decided to group and name their series differently, the longest could have been (181 chars): *Onii-chan dakedo ai sae areba kankei nai yo ne! Specials - Shinsaku Anime Eizo dakedo nanimo monku nai yo ne! Episode 01: Oishii okome no Akiko-machi no shuukaku ga tanoshimi da ne!*. If you restricted it to TV anime titles I'd trust it more, since the biggest difference seems to be in how to deal with subtitles of specials/movies.

Comment: Ummm in the DB title is an error, there is no word that would be transcribed into "sens"... and imdb says its romanization is "Doragon bôru Z: Tatta hitori no saishuu kessen - Furiiza ni itonda Z senshi Kakarotto no chichi". IMO the criteria how to count the length of the title should be more clear.

Comment: Naruto Narutimate Hero 3 [blablabla] isn't the original title. The original title is: Naruto Narutimate Hero 3: Tsuini Gekitotsu! Jounin tai Genin!! Musabetsu Dairansen taikai Kaisai!! which is only 98 characters long.

Answer (score 12):

I took all anime titles from [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?c[0]=a&c[1]=b&c[2]=c&o=3&q=&tag=&sy=0&sm=0&sd=0&ey=0&em=0&ed=0&show=0), parsed and sorted them by length:

```
Dragon Ball Z Special 1: Tatta Hitori no Saishuu Kessen - Freezer ni Idonda Z Senshi Son Goku no Chi    100
Naruto: Dai Katsugeki!! Yuki Hime Shinobu Houjou Dattebayo! Special: Konoha Annual Sports Festival  98
Detective Conan Magic File 2: Kudou Shinichi - The Case of the Mysterious Wall and the Black Lab    96
Crayon Shin-chan Manatsu no Yoru ni Ora Sanjou! Arashi wo Yobu Den-O VS Shin-O 60-bu Special!!  94
Meitantei Holmes: Mrs. Hudson Hitojichi Jiken no Maki / Dover Kaikyouno Daikuuchuusen no Maki   93
Digimon Adventure 02: Digimon Hurricane Jouriku!! / Chouzetsu Shinka!! Ougon no Digimental  90
Pokemon Best Wishes! Season 2: Decolora Adventure - Dent to Takeshi! Gyarados no Gekirin!!  90
Bishoujo Senshi Sailor Moon SuperS: Sailor 9 Senshi Shuuketsu! Black Dream Hole no Kiseki   89
Senki Zesshou Symphogear G: In the Distance, That Day, When the Star Became Music... OVA    88
Detective Conan Magic File 3: Shinichi and Ran - Memories of Mahjong Tiles and Tanabata 87
Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex 2nd GIG - Individual Eleven - Tachikoma no Hibi 87
Mahou Shoujo Madoka★Magica Movie 3: Hangyaku no Monogatari - Magica Quartet x Nisioisin 87
Dragon Ball Z Special 2: Zetsubou e no Hankou!! Nokosareta Chousenshi - Gohan to Trunks 87
Detective Conan OVA 07: A Challenge from Agasa! Agasa vs. Conan and the Detective Boys  86
Detective Conan OVA 05: The Target is Kogoro! The Detective Boys' Secret Investigation  86
Pokemon Fushigi no Dungeon: Sora no Tankentai - Toki to Yami wo Meguru Saigo no Bouken  86
Yatterman the Movie: Shin Yattermecha Osu Gou! Omocha no Kuni de Dai Ketsudan da Koron  86
Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex - Solid State Society 3D - Tachikoma no Hibi    84
Ichigo 100%: Koi ga Hajimaru?! Satsuei Gasshuku - Yureru Kokoro ga Higashi e Nishi e    84
Keroro Gunsou Movie 5: Tanjou! Kyuukyoku Keroro, Kiseki no Jikuu-jima, de arimasu!! 83
Chouyaku Hyakuninisshu: Uta Koi. - Sake to Kikoushi ~ Murasaki Kishikibu to Kintou  82
Kagachi-sama Onagusame Tatematsurimasu: Netorare Mura Inya Hanashi - The Animation  82
Saint Seiya: The Hades Chapter Sanctuary - Yomigaerishi Gold Saint-tachi no Shinwa  82
Astro Boy Tetsuwan Atom Tokubetsu Hen: Ivan no Wakusei - Robot to Ningen no Yuujou  82
Puchimas!: Petit iDOLM@STER - Takatsuki Gold Densetsu Special!! Harukasan Matsuri   81
```

This is from [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?list=9) (parsing is not ideal and some titles have "-phrases like this-" in them):

```
Chō Gekijō-ban Keroro Gunsō Tanjō! Kyūkyoku Keroro Kiseki no Jikūjima de Arimasu!!  82
Legend of the Galactic Heroes: A Hundred Billion Stars, A Hundred Billion Lights    80
Prince Mackaroo: Peril at the Full Moon Road - A 'Rare' Adventure of Our Prince-    80
Soreike! Anpanman: Minna Atsumare! Anpanman World Komusubiman to Omatsuri Robot 79
Suteki desu wa, Sakura-chan! Tomoyo no Cardcaptor Sakura Katsuyaku Video Nikki! 79
Animation Seisaku Shinkō Kuromi-chan: Nippon no Anime wa Watashi ga Tsukuru! 2  78
Himitsu Kessha Taka no Tsume THE MOVIE II ~Watashi o Ai Shita Kuro Oolong-cha~  78
Tantei Opera Milky Holmes Alternative TWO -Kobayashi Opera to Kokū no Ōgarasu-  78
Chō Gekijōban Keroro Gunsō 3: Keroro Tai Keroro - Tenkū Daikessen de Arimasu!   77
Tantei Opera Milky Holmes Alternative ONE -Kobayashi Opera to 5-mai no Kaiga-   77
Glass no Kamen Desu ga Onna Spy no Koi! Murasaki no Bara wa Kiken na Kaori!?    76
Detective Conan: Conan Edogawa & Heiji Hattori versus Kid the Phantom Thief 75
Ham Ham Grand Prix - The Miracle of Aurora Valley ~Ribon-chan's Close Call~ 75
Hamuchanzu no Takara Sagashi Daisaku - Hamuhaa! Sutekina Umi no Natsuyasumi 75
Himitsu Kessha Taka no Tsume The Movie 3 ~http://takanotsume.jp wa Eien ni~ 75
Meitantei Conan: Agasa kara no Chōsenjō! Agasa vs. Conan & Shōnen Tanteidan 75
My mental choices are completely interfering with my school romantic comedy 75
Tsubasa RESERVoir CHRoNiCLE the Movie: The Princess in the Birdcage Kingdom 75
Japan Air Self Defence Force Tactical Training Squadron 801 T.T.S. Airbats  74
Tottoko Hamutaro: Ham Ham Paradi-chu! Hamutarō to Fushigi no Oni no Ehonto  74
Tottoko Hamutaro: Hamutaro no Otanjōbi - Mama o Tazunete Sanzen Techitechi  74
Kikaider-01: The Animation: Guitar o Motta Shōnen - Kikaider vs. Inazuman   73
Maison Ikkoku: Prelude, When the Cherry Blossoms in the Springtime Return   73
Super Doll Licca-chan: Licca-chan Zettai Zetsumei! Doll Knights no Kiseki   73
Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions: Depth of Field - Love and Hate Theater    72
Magical Witch Academy - Boku to Sensei no Magical Lesson - The Animation    72
Maji de Otaku na English! Ribbon-chan: Eigo de Tatakau Mahō Shōjo the TV    72
Slam Dunk: Hoero Basketman Tamashii! Hanamichi to Rukawa no Atsuki Natsu    72
Tony's Heroine Series: Kanojo wa Hanayome Kōhosei? Cinderella Collection    72
Chōjū Kishin Dancougar: Ushinawareta Mono-tachi e no Chinkonka [Requiem]    72    
Ore no Nōnai Sentakushi ga, Gakuen Love Come o Zenryoku de Jama Shiteiru    72
Gekijō-ban Anime Nintama Rantaro Ninjutsu Gakuen Zenin Shutsudō! no Dan 71
Precure All-Stars DX3 Mirai ni Todoke! Sekai o Tsunagu Niji-Iro no Hana 71
Street Fighter II: Yomigaeru Fujiwara-kyō - Toki o Kaketa Fighter-tachi 71
Chiisana Kyojin Microman: Daigekisen! Microman VS Saikyō Senshi Gorgon  70
Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion R2 Special Edition 'Zero Requiem'  70
Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion Special Edition 'Black Rebellion'  70
Dream 9 Toriko & One Piece & Dragon Ball Z Chō Collaboration Special!!  70
Gekijōban Pocket Monster Best Wishes! Victini to Shiroki Eiyū Reshiram  70
```

This list is from [Anime Planet](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/all) titles:

```
Detective Conan Magic File 2: Kudo Shinichi: The Case of the Mysterious Wall and the Black Lab  94
Bishoujo Senshi Sailor Moon Super S: Sailor 9 Senshi Shuuketsu! Black-Dream-Hole no Kiseki  90
Glass no Kamen Desu ga the Movie: Onna Spy no Koi! Murasaki no Bara wa Kiken na Kaori!? 87
Detective Conan Magic File 3: Shinichi and Ran: Memories of Mahjong Tiles and Tanabata  86
Chou Gekijouban Keroro Gunsou 5: Kyuukyoku Keroro, Kiseki no Jikuu-jima, de arimasu!!   85
Detective Conan OVA 5: The Target is Kogoro! The Detective Boys' Secret Investigation   85
Meitantei Conan OVA 7: Agasa-sensei no Chousenjou! Agasa vs Conan &Shounen Tanteidan    84
My youth romantic comedy is wrong as I expected., My Teen RomanticComedy SNAFU OVA  82
Hamtaro Movie 3: Ham Ham Gran Prix Aurora Tani no Kiseki: Ribbon-chanKiki Ippatsu   81
Zettai Karen Children: Generous Treatment! Natsuko and Hotaru's B.A.B.E.L. Report   81
Puchimas! Petit iDOLM@STER - Takatsuki Gold Densetsu Special!! Harukasan Matsuri    80
Legend of the Galactic Heroes: A Hundred Billion Stars, A Hundred Billion Lights    80
Mobile Suit Zeta Gundam: A New Translation III -Love is the Pulse of the Stars- 79
My Mental Choices are Completely Interfering with my School Romantic Comedy OVA 79
One Piece Movie 8: The Desert Princess and the Pirates - Adventures in Alabasta 79
Engaged to the Unidentified: Mite. Are ga Watashitachi no Tomatteiru Ryokan yo. 79
Gekijouban Metal Fight Beyblade vs Taiyou: Shakunetsu no Shinryakusha Sol Blaze 79
Kidou Senshi Gundam SEED Destiny Special Edition Kanketsu Hen: Jiyuu no Daishou 79
Mobile Suit Gundam SEED Destiny Special Edition III: The Hell Fire of Destiny   77
Yatterman: Shin Yattermecha Osu gou! Omocha no Kuni de Dai Ketsudan da Koron!   77
```

Get [the unparsed pages](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9dzgs_dkXAIaVkzN1Jfek5oYnc/edit?usp=sharing) containing all these titles saved as text, and maybe you'll be able to parse it better than me!

Comment: [AnoHana](http://myanimelist.net/anime/9989/Ano_Hi_Mita_Hana_no_Namae_wo_Bokutachi_wa_Mada_Shiranai.) has a dot at the end of its name, bringing it to the length of WataMote.

Answer (score 2):

Some pretty good contenders are:

> Kochira Katsushikaku Kameari Kouenmae Hashutsujo The Movie 2: UFO Shuurai! Tornado Daisakusen
>
> Doraemon the Movie: Nobita's New Great Adventure into the Underworld - The Seven Magic Users
>
> Detective Conan Magic File 2: Kudou Shinichi - The Case of the Mysterious Wall and the Black Lab

And as a bonus, I discovered a Gintama Episode (S2 Ep.53) with a particularly long name:

> "Sutoresu wa hage no gen'in ni naru ga sutoresu o tamenai yōni ki o kubaruto sokode mata sutoresu ga tamarunode kekkyoku bokurani dekiru koto nante nanimo nai"

or

> "Stress Makes You Bald, But It's Stressful To Avoid Stress, So You End Up Stressed Out Anyway, So In The End There's Nothing You Can Do"

Answer (score 1):

The longest name that I can find (excluding spin-offs, movies, second season, and special editions etc, that have extended subtitles as opposed to the main show) is "Shuumatsu Nani Shitemasu ka? Isogashii Desu ka? Sukutte Moratte Ii Desu ka?" which has 75 characters (61 alphanumeric) and translates to "WorldEnd: What are you doing at the end of the world? Are you busy? Will you save us?"

Comment: Interesting to disregard spin-offs/etc., and not surprising that spin-offs (which might well include the title of the accepted answer) might beat this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any anime with really long titles, the longest title I have seen so far was probably Interstella 5555: The 5tory of the 5ecret 5tar 5ystem or Martian Successor Nadesico: The Motion Picture—Prince of Darkness. That's probably not the longest though.